# Where can I go to have a rant about Open GEO Data?

Tags: data

Which is the most popular GIS forum or website that's not under the control of our corporate or government overlords?

This place is great for questions and answers, but if I want to have a discussion or in this case a rant about the state of open data access in the GIS community, which is the most popular forum for such things?

p.s Don't worry, I'll be marking this as a community wiki myself ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if they will welcome rants but if you have questions you could try our sister site https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions

Answer (score 0):

The [talk-GB OpenStreetMap](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/listinfo/talk-gb) lists might be an ok place to *discuss* open data issues and the like. Even though it is mostly an OpenStreetMap based email list people do talk about OpenData, licensing and so forth. You might want to skim through their [archives](http://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk-gb/) and see if their is anything relevant and see what kind of things are discussed.